# remove gap between input and button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a button right near to a text field.

Here the code I thought would make it work

```
<input class="txt" type="text" name="name">
<button class="btn">Submit</button>


.txt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  outline: none;
  margin:0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rm9etsny/

However, there is still a gap between the 2 elements. How can I remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can put your html content inline. That will remove the space without having margin-left as negative

```
<input class="txt" type="text" name="name"><button class="btn">Submit</button>
```

Also to put them align in a horizontal row, you need to consider giving some less % to input.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/rm9etsny/5/

Comment: This seems to solve the issue but why do I have to add negative margin? Is there a way to achieve what I wish without using this trick?

Comment: yeah i think it'll do @macsig

Comment: yeah, If you also add ```* {
   box-sizing: border-box;  
}``` you can keep 80/20 and there is no need to use less %.  http://jsfiddle.net/torbcfuh/

Comment: To keep the two elements on separate lines a comment may be added between them http://jsfiddle.net/torbcfuh/1/

Comment: @ macsig: yes that's the best way to do it. It keeps your code readable. I just added inline since there are only 2 elements in example. In normal cases comment added is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is because inline-blocks give extra spacing between two items you can prevent it by using `float:left` or adding parent with `font-size:0` by using `box-sizing:border-box` the padding is given from inside

eg

if the input width is `100%` and padding is `15px` so the total width will be 100% + 15px `box-sizing:border-box` gives the `padding` from inside

In my example i have changed the border to `outset`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/rm9etsny/11/

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
}
div {
    font-size:0;
}
.txt {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline: none;
    padding: 15px;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;

}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="name" />
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Instead of using an unnecessary div with font-size: 0 I prefer to inline the elements and to put a comment between them.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust as per your requirement by some change in values.

```
   .txt{
  border:1px solid black;
  color:black;
  height:50px;
  width:400px;
  left:30%;
  position:absolute;
  }

 .btn{
 background:black;
 border:1px solid black;
 color:white;
 height:40px;
 width:60px;
 top:3%;
 right:33%;
 position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set negative value for margin-top on .btn element, eg.:

```
margin-top: -3px;
```

Comment: The gap I'm talking about is not vertical but horizontal. Currently the button is under the field because there is horizontal gap between the elements so since the field is 80% and the button 20% with gap the total is more than 100% and the button is pushed under the field. Just try to set the with od the field as 60% http://jsfiddle.net/zzgor1po/ and you see the issue.